# "song-lyric" tag should be change to just "lyrics"?

Tags: discussion

Should the [song-lyric](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/song-lyric) tag be changed to just [lyrics](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lyrics)?  It seems to me that saying the word "song" is redundant  and this tag would be perfectly understandable with the song portion.  It would also allow the tag to cover poems and haikus as well.

edit: did not know there was a poems tag already.  So we'd just keep that poetry tag seperate.  This question is specifically about renaming song-lyric tag ot just lyrics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fine with the renaming...

but I see no good reason to merge [poetry](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) and [lyrics](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lyrics)... It's not like we are running on a limited number of tags, and these two are quite different (I don't think Ayumi Hamasaki and Matsuo Basho really belong in the same sentence, let alone the same tag).

Comment: edited question for clarificaiton

Comment: Thanks. In that case, I am completely in favour of streamlining the tag name. 'lyrics' sounds good.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see renaming the tag to help or hurt either way. I'm totally indifferent to it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not against renaming [song-lyric](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/song-lyric) to [lyrics](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lyrics), but if we want to include poems, isn’t it better to change it to [poetry](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry)?

Comment: edited question for clarification